# ios objectiv-c strange behavior connecting to asmx webservice (c# on IIS )

Tags: ios, objective-c, iis, asmx

i have a simple asmx web service. it was used in our old winphone app and now i want to use it in new apps. xamarin.forms app on android works nicely. tests from local web page works nicely. But with ios/objective C app i completely missed.

i installed local iis (on w10 notebook), service works nicely from browser, can be debugged, etc.

in iis logs requests from browser and an app seems alike, but result is different

```
'2019-07-05 09:00:35 fe80::54ae:f86a:269:32ce%14 POST /ws/bcws.asmx/GetCurrencyList - 80 - fe80::54ae:f86a:269:32ce%14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:67.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/67.0 http://ish-xps/ws/bcws.asmx?op=GetCurrencyList 200 0 0 780'

'2019-07-05 09:06:17 192.168.101.159 POST /ws/bcws.asmx/GetCurrencyList - 80 - 192.168.101.137 bc2+IOS+request businesscalc 500 0 0 9'
```

when i connect to it from mac (on the same wifi network) or ipad on the same network . it fails with exception (below)

i installed fiddler as a reverse proxy. my app works nicely through fiddler but getting an exception from server if i connect directly

i am changing only single line of code

```
#define SERVER_ADDR @"ish-xps"
```

to

```
#define SERVER_ADDR @"ish-xps:8888"
```

below is the request code

may be somebody have idea what i am doing wrong ?
thanks in advance 
ish

```
-(BOOL) GetCurrencyList
{
    soapReq_GetCurrencyList = @" \
    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> \
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \
    <soap:Body> \
    <GetCurrencyList xmlns=\"http://ish-xps/ws\" /> \
    </soap:Body> \
    </soap:Envelope> \
    \
    ";
    [self sendToServerWithRequest:soapReq_GetCurrencyList];
    return (true);
}
    -(BOOL) sendToServerWithRequest:(NSString *)req
{
    NSString *connectStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/ws/bcws.asmx/GetCurrencyList", SERVER_ADDR];
    NSURL *serverUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:connectStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:serverUrl];
    NSString *reqLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long) req.length];
    NSString *soapAction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/ws/GetCurrencyList",SERVER_ADDR];

    [request addValue:@"bc2 IOS request" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [request addValue:SERVER_ADDR forHTTPHeaderField:@"HOST"];
    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:reqLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request addValue:soapAction forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:@"businesscalc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[req dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connect)
    {
        return (true);
    }
    else
    {
        return (false);
    }

}
```

```
    Server Error in '/ws' Application.
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetCurrencyList'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetCurrencyList'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetCurrencyList'.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +401372
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +281
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +89
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +564
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +263
```

Answer (score 0):

well, 
i sorted out this problem and found answers for all questions except - why xamarin.forms on android version working. ;)

questions and answers:
1)app working through fiddler and not working directly.
there is an article on telerik web site about some situation where fiddler may cure some of the app's networking problems 
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/details/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-

2) server exception . was cured with known solution 
added

```
 <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
```

to application webconfig
details here 
https://web.archive.org/web/20100523032751/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267

but i can't understand why xamarin.forms version works on android and why it works through fiddler

Comment: seems this is not an answer, but workaround, as it enable invoke button from remote computer